# How to add disable selected option in select2 dropdown ul container

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#location_preferences_country").select2({
    tags: false,
}).on("change", function(e) {
    var country_codes = $('#location_preferences_country').val();
    var $searchfield = $(this).parent().find('.select2-search__field');

    // Check if the selected value is 'Any'
    if (country_codes == 'Any') {
        $searchfield.prop('disabled', true);
        $('#location_preferences_state').val(null).trigger('change');
        $('#location_preferences_state').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        $('#location_preferences_state').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {

        $searchfield.prop('disabled', false);
        $('#location_preferences_state').prop('disabled', false);
        localselectstate(); // Assuming this function handles the logic for showing the state dropdown list.
    }
});
```

How to dropdown list hide when  if (country_codes == 'Any') else dropdownl list show.select2 pluign

Comment: What's the plugin you're using? What do you have already (current behavior)? What do you want to do (expected behavior)?